# Show one record from typo3 extension

Tags: php, typo3, backend, query-builder, typo3-extensions

I have develop a typo3 extension to show some records in a list.
I need to show just one record from this extension in another section of the web page.
How can select just one record from editor and show that in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Insert flexform with a selector for your table into the plugin and let editor select record with that. Then in your action use `getByUid` method on your repository to fetch the selected record. You might also need to set Storage page on the content element, if your repository respects that.